# Clueless error 500 on rest paypal payment execution

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm setting up a paypal payment option on the project i'm working on.

The authorization structure I use is an hybrid client + server REST.
The client generates the token as expected, after the user clicks "Pay now" on the paypal page.

Then the server receives its data (paymentID and payerID). So, i just ask for a bearer token (or use the one i had stored) and reach the

```
POST /payments/payment/{payment_id}/execute
```

endpoint, with no body at all.

Everything works fine, until the REST request, since it gives me a 500 error and no explanation at all of what I could have done wrong. Just in case some PayPal developers are reading this post, i'll also leave the debug id:

```
d78e7ca9e79b2
```

Another strange thing is that the

```
GET /payments/payment/{payment_id}/
```

request is working fine, also giving me as HATEOAS endpoint, the execute link, identical as the one I use. Did i miss something, in the execute call, so?

Comment: Without more detail on how you're doing `Execute`, _only Paypal support devs_ will be able to help you with what you have posted

Comment: I know right. My hope was also that. Anyway by exploring with cURL i noted that empty body or malformed request caused the paypal server to 500, whilst sending even the most stupid json, {} caused it to 400. It expected another field in the body, the payer_id, in a different casing flavor from the one paypal itself used in the checkout.js library. (payerID = payer_id)